# Functional equation Archimedean exterior square

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory

Is there any reference where the **functional equation of the Jacquet-Shalika integral representation of the Archimedean local exterior-square L-function** is established? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This doesn't appear in the literature. There is work of Kewat-Raghunathan for the nonarchimedean version of this, as well as work of Matringe and subsequently Cogdell-Matringe. I expect that one can prove the functional equation in the archimedean setting via similar methods of Jacquet in his work on archimedean Rankin-Selberg integrals.